# Problemas Shiny con checkbox y grafico de barras

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

Realizo la siguiente app pero en el gráfico de barras no consigo poner el nombre debajo de las barras.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id="sbmenu",
              menuItem("Apartado1",tabName = "DR" ,
                       menuSubItem('Resumen Apartado1', tabName = 'menu11'),
                       menuSubItem('Apartado 2', tabName = 'menu12'),
                       menuSubItem('Apartado 3', tabName = 'menu13')
              ),

              menuItem("menu2_",tabName = "menu2" ,
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 1', tabName = 'menu21'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 2', tabName = 'menu22'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 3', tabName = 'menu23')
              ),

              menuItem("menu3_",tabName = "menu3" ,
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 1', tabName = 'menu31'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 2', tabName = 'menu32'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 3', tabName = 'menu33')
              ),

              menuItem("menu4_",tabName = "menu4" ,
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 1', tabName = 'menu41'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 2', tabName = 'menu42'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 3', tabName = 'menu43')
              ),

              menuItem("menu5_",tabName = "menu5" ,
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 1', tabName = 'menu51'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 2', tabName = 'menu52'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 3', tabName = 'menu53')
              ),

              menuItem("menu6_",tabName = "menu6",
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 1', tabName = 'menu61'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 2', tabName = 'menu62'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 3', tabName = 'menu63')
              ),
              menuItem("menu7_",tabName = "menu7",
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 1', tabName = 'menu61'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 2', tabName = 'menu62'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 3', tabName = 'menu63')
              ),
              menuItem("menu8_",tabName = "menu8",
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 1', tabName = 'menu61'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 2', tabName = 'menu62'),
                       menuSubItem('Sub Menu 3', tabName = 'menu63')
              )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem("menu11",h1("Apartado 1"), tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                                   tabPanel("Comidas",fluidRow(
                                                     checkboxGroupInput("Comidas_DR", "Comidas DR", inline = TRUE,
                                                                        table(factor(c(rep("Peras", 1000), rep("Naranjas", 560),
                                                                                       rep("Platanos", 2100), rep("Uvas", 700), rep("Melon", 1500),
                                                                                       rep("Sandia", 750), rep("Melocoton", 2200), rep("Pomelo", 1050),
                                                                                       rep("Fresa", 1250)), levels = c("Peras","Naranjas","Platanos","Uvas","Melon","Sandia",
                                                                                                                       "Melocoton","Pomelo","Fresa")))

                                                     ),
                                                     title = "Grafico",
                                                     plotOutput(outputId = "barplot1")
                                                   ))
    )),
    tabItem("menu12",h1("Pagina 2 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu13",h1("Pagina 3 en construccion")),

    tabItem("menu21",h1("Pagina 1 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu22",h1("Pagina 2 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu23",h1("Pagina 3 en construccion")),

    tabItem("menu31",h1("Pagina 1 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu32",h1("Pagina 2 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu33",h1("Pagina 3 en construccion")),

    tabItem("menu41",h1("Pagina 1 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu42",h1("Pagina 2 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu43",h1("Pagina 3 en construccion")),

    tabItem("menu51",h1("Pagina 1 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu52",h1("Pagina 2 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu53",h1("Pagina 3 en construccion")),

    tabItem("menu61",h1("Pagina 1 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu62",h1("Pagina 2 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu63",h1("Pagina 3 en construccion")),

    tabItem("menu71",h1("Pagina 1 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu72",h1("Pagina 2 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu73",h1("Pagina 3 en construccion")),

    tabItem("menu81",h1("Pagina 1 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu82",h1("Pagina 2 en construccion")),
    tabItem("menu83",h1("Pagina 3 en construccion"))
  )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'Comidas', titleWidth = 290),
  sidebar,
  body
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe(print(input$sbmenu))


  output$barplot1 <- renderPlot({
    barplot(as.numeric(input$Comidas_DR),
            xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 2500),col = rainbow(9),
            names.arg = names(input$Comidas_DR))


            grid()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

La interfaz de este ejemplo sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera incorporar las etiquetas de cada selección debajo de cada barra, lo he intentado mediante `names.arg = names(input$Comidas_DR)` pero sin éxito.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, es importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `input$Comidas_DR` es un vector sencillo con las opciones seleccionadas, en tu ejemplo es la frecuencia de cada fruta, y `names(input$Comidas_DR)` lamentablemente, no te retorna los nombres. En primer lugar reformularía los datos en una estructura más amigable para trabajar, colocado a nivel global (al comienzo del script) haría:

```
x <- table(factor(c(rep("Peras", 1000), rep("Naranjas", 560),
                    rep("Platanos", 2100), rep("Uvas", 700), rep("Melon", 1500),
                    rep("Sandia", 750), rep("Melocoton", 2200), rep("Pomelo", 1050),
                    rep("Fresa", 1250)), levels = c("Peras","Naranjas","Platanos","Uvas","Melon","Sandia",
                                                    "Melocoton","Pomelo","Fresa")))


opciones <- as.data.frame(x, 
                          row.names = names(x),
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[,2,drop=FALSE]

opciones$NR <- 1:nrow(opciones)
opciones

          Freq NR
Peras     1000  1
Naranjas   560  2
Platanos  2100  3
Uvas       700  4
Melon     1500  5
Sandia     750  6
Melocoton 2200  7
Pomelo    1050  8
Fresa     1250  9
```

En `opciones` ahora tenemos un `data.frame` con los nombres de cada fruta como nombres de fila (esto es más amigable con el barplot, si quisieras ver el cuadro de leyendas), la frecuencia, y un número de fila. La configuración del selector sería:

```
checkboxGroupInput("Comidas_DR", 
                   "Comidas DR", 
                   inline = TRUE,
                   choiceNames = rownames(opciones),
                   choiceValues = opciones$NR)
```

Configuramos la etiqueta de la opción y el valor a retornar, que será el número de fila. Lo siguiente sería actualizar el `barlot`:

```
    x = opciones[as.numeric(input$Comidas_DR),]
    barplot(x[, -2],
            xlim = c(0, 10), 
            ylim = c(0, 2500),
            col = rainbow(9),
            names.arg = rownames(x))
```

Simplemente filtramos el `dta.frame` inicial, con las opciones elegidas. En `rownames(x)` tendremos las leyendas que queremos debajo de cada barra, con `x[, -2]` nos quedamos solamente con las frecuencias

Comment: Muchas gracias. No encontraba la solución y no era tan difícil de ver. Le estoy muy agradecido.

Comment: Hola @GabrielEsteban, si la respuesta funcionó, sugiero que sea acepta, [¿Cómo funciona la aceptación de respuestas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) esto no sólo aumentará tus puntos y la posibilidad de que ganes más medallas, sino que permitirá a la comunidad estar enfocada en ayudar a otros miembros con las preguntas no resueltas.